# Remove all rows from pandas dataframe based on count of dinstict values in categorical column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have used cars dataframe with many columns. If i get count of appearance of certain manufacturer with:

```
carsDF.manufacturer.value_counts()
```

result is something like:

```
 VW               2228
 Opel             1414
 Renault          1362
 Audi              895
 BMW               888
 Mercedes-Benz     786
```

How can I remove all rows from dataframe with certain manufacturer if that  manufacturer has total count of appearance less than certain number?

Comment: `df[df.total_count < x]`, where `x` is certain number?

Comment: But it has to be only if total_count of rows where certian"manufacturer" is less than x

Comment: Could you add an example of input and the expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a map:

```
# get the count for each manufacturer
counts = carsDF.manufacturer.value_counts()

# threshold
thresh = 1000

# replace the manufacturer with the counts and thresholding
carsDF[carsDF.manufacturer.map(counts).ge(thresh)]
```

Comment: Great answer. Correct solution should have .gt(thresh) because I need all above threshold. Your solution is giving me everything below threshold. Change that so I can accept your answer.

Comment: .ge didn't work for me - gave me same df. gt works well.

Comment: `.ge` is equivalent to `>=`, whereas `.gt` is equivalent to `>`.  One can also speed this up by not sorting the `.value_counts`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. According to your statement *remove ... less than certain number*, it should be `ge`. But you can always modify the question/answer to your need.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way which uses `loc` on the value count result to filter the manufacturers for those that exceed a minimum count value.

```
# Sample data.
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'manufacturer': 
        ['VW'] * 2228 
        + ['Opel'] * 1414 
        + ['Renault'] * 1362
        + ['Audi'] * 895
        + ['BMW'] * 888
        + ['Mercedes-Benz'] * 787}
)
```

Solution:

```
min_count = 1000
main_manufacturers = set(
    df['manufacturer'].value_counts(sort=False).loc[lambda x: x >= min_count].index)
df = df.loc[df['manufacturer'].isin(main_manufacturers)]
```